# Passing data to a Bootstrap modal in jinja template (one of them from inside a for loop)

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

I have a jinja template with 2 variables (one of them inside a for loop) and I want to pass them to a bootstrap modal in order to confirm a delete that is triggered within the loop.
The schema of it is something like this:

```
<object_outside_loop>
<!-- Loop -->
{% for item_inside_loop in items %}
    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal">Delete</button>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Modal -->
<my-modal-here>
    <a href="{{ url_for('delete_something', id1=object_outside_loop._id, id2=item_inside_loop._id) }}" >Confirm Delete</a>
</my-modal-here>
```

and I need to pass both variables (id1 and id2) from the modal to my route:

```
@app.route("/delete_something/<id1>/<id2>")
def delete_something(id1, id2):

    mongo.db.something.update_one(
        {"_id": ObjectId(id2)},
        {"$pull": {"something": {"_id": ObjectId(id1)}}},
    )
    flash("Your something has been updated!", "success")
    return redirect(url_for("somewhere", id=id2))
```

How can I pass those two variables to the modal, and how do I do that without breaking the endpoint?

Comment: Is the `my-modal-here` inside the `object_outside_loop`?

Comment: The object_outside_loop is reachable by the modal, as it is present globally. I don’t know hot to pass data from the loop to it.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below...

**Asumption:** `id` of your modal is `my-modal`

Change how you are displaying the `Delete` button:

```py
{% for item_inside_loop in items %}
    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-url="{{url_for('delete_something', id1=object_outside_loop._id, id2=item_inside_loop._id)}}">Delete</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Change the `Delete` button, which in modal to:

```html
<a id="confirm-delete">Confirm Delete</a>
```

Now, on click of `Delete` button in modal, change it to:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my-modal").on("show.bs.modal", function(event){
        // Get the button that triggered the modal
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

        // Extract value from the custom data-* attribute
        var url = button.data("url");
        $(this).find('#confirm-delete').attr('href', url)
    });
});
```

I hope the above works for you.